# How to insert data using kafka and cassandra

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect

I referred this documentation:

http://itechseeker.com/en/tutorials-2/apache-cassandra/install-apache-cassandra/

[https://lenses.io/blog/2018/03/cassandra-to-kafka/#:~:text=Adding%20the%20Cassandra%20Source%20connector,Connect%20through%20the%20REST%20API](https://lenses.io/blog/2018/03/cassandra-to-kafka/#:%7E:text=Adding%20the%20Cassandra%20Source%20connector,Connect%20through%20the%20REST%20API)

For how to connect Kafka and Cassandra. Kafka and Cassandra's connection was successfully established. but when I tried to insert data using Kafka to Cassandra it was throwing **CassandraJsonWriter Error**. How to fix this issue and I am new to this concept.

**connect-standalone.properties**:

```
plugin.path=/kafka/plugins
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

[image: CassandraJsonWriter Error]

**Error Log**:

```
[2022-06-28 16:45:03,699] ERROR [cassandra-sink-orders|task-0] There was an error writing the records Boxed Error  
 (com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter:172)                                            java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error  
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.resolver(Promise.scala:87)                                                            at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$$resolveTry(Promise.scala:79)                           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)                                          at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete(Promise.scala:53)                                                                  at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete$(Promise.scala:52)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:187)                                             at scala.concurrent.Promise.failure(Promise.scala:104)                                                                  at scala.concurrent.Promise.failure$(Promise.scala:104)                                                                 at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.failure(Promise.scala:187)                                              at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.common.concurrent.ExecutorExtension$RunnableWrapper$.$anonfun$submit$1(ExecutorExtension.scala:34)                                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                                                                at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.common.converters.ToJsonWithProjections$.apply(ToJsonWithProjections.scala:97)                                                                                                                             at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter.$anonfun$insert$2(CassandraJsonWriter.scala:185)                                                                                                                at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter.$anonfun$insert$2$adapted(CassandraJsonWriter.scala:179)                                                                                                        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:154)                                                           at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter.insert(CassandraJsonWriter.scala:179)                                                                                                                           at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter.$anonfun$write$4(CassandraJsonWriter.scala:159)                                                                                                                 at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter.$anonfun$write$4$adapted(CassandraJsonWriter.scala:157)
```

**cassandra connector properties**:

```
name=cassandra-sink-orders
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=five-topic
connect.cassandra.port=9042
connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
connect.cassandra.key.space=testkeyspace
connect.cassandra.username=cassandra
connect.cassandra.password=cassandra
connect.cassandra.kcql=INSERT INTO emp SELECT * FROM five-topic
connect.progress.enabled=true
```

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace as text, not an image. Also show your cassandra connector properties

Comment: @OneCricketeer I updated error stack trace and Cassandra properties. can you check it

Comment: In one of your edits - `Scala module 2.12.6 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.12.0 and < 2.13.0`... , so you have a classpath issue. Seems like may be an installation issue,or a bug that should be reported here https://github.com/lensesio/stream-reactor/issues Note that the blog you're reading is 4 years old and definitely would use older versions of the connector, Cassandra, Java, Scala, etc, so read the latest docs https://docs.lenses.io/3.0/connectors/sink/cassandra.html